# Is there a way to unlink all the charts in a Google slide presentation in one go?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I am trying to accomplish this using AppScript using Slides API. However, I am a JS noob. Please help.

```
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
        .addItem('Batch Update Charts', 'batchUpdate')
        .addToUi();
}

function batchUpdate(){
    var gotSlides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();

    for (var i = 0; i < gotSlides.ID; i++) {
        var slide = gotSlides[i];
        var sheetsCharts = slide.getChartId();
        for (var k = 0; k < sheetsCharts.ID; k++) {
            var shChart = sheetsCharts[k];
            var requests = [{
                createSheetsChart: {
                    chartId: shChart,
                    linkingMode: 'NOT_LINKED_IMAGE',
                }
            }];
            shChart.refresh()
            requests: requests       
        }
    }
}
```

This code is totally inaccurate. I hope this will give you some pointers on what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm guessing [``removeLink()``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/sheets-chart#removeLink()) didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the URL/indexed link in a sheet chart, not the linked chart property from it:

You can use `removeLink()` for every `SheetsChart` in every slide. Refer https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/sheets-chart#removeLink()

```
function removeAllSheetsChartLinks() {
  SlidesApp.openById(SLIDE_ID).getSlides()
  .forEach(function(s) {
    s.getSheetsCharts().forEach(function(c) {
      if (c.getLink() != null) c.removeLink();
    });
  });
}
```

But, if you mean to remove the linked chart property, you have to delete the current sheet chart that you want to remove the linked chart property from and create a new sheet chart with the same properties as the original sheet chart but with `linkingMode: 'NOT_LINKED_IMAGE'` property. It is because there is no direct Slides API request for such functionality.
https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#LinkingMode

```
function removeLinkChartExample() {

  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(SLIDE_ID);
  //if empty
  if (presentation == null) throw new Error('Presentation was not found');
  Logger.log("%s id = %s", presentation.getName(), presentation.getId());
  
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  if (slides == null) throw new Error('Slides were not found');
  Logger.log("Total of slides in %s: %d", presentation.getName(), slides.length);


  //refresh all linked sheet charts
  slides.forEach(function(s) {
    s.getSheetsCharts().forEach(function(c) {
      //if (c.getLink() != null) 
      { Logger.log("LINKED CHART TITLE: %s, \"%s\"",c.getTitle(), c.getSpreadsheetId()); c.refresh(); } 
    });
  });
  
  var chartToRemoveLinkedChart = slides[0]; //sheet that you want to remove its linked chart property
  if (chartToRemoveLinkedChart == null) return;
  
  var presentationId = presentation.getId();
  
  var sheetObjectId = chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getObjectId();
  Logger.log("Sheet ObjectId of \"%s\": %s", chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getTitle(), sheetObjectId);
  var presentationStaffChartId = chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getObjectId();
  Logger.log("Linked Chart ObjectId of \"%s\": %s", chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getTitle(), presentationStaffChartId);
  var spreadsheetId = chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getSpreadsheetId();
  Logger.log("SS Id of \"%s\": %s", chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getTitle(), spreadsheetId);
  var chartId = chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getChartId();
  Logger.log("SS Chart Id of \"%s\": %s", chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getTitle(), chartId);
  var width = chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getWidth();
  Logger.log("Chart width of \"%s\": %s", chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getTitle(), width);
  var height = chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getHeight();
  Logger.log("Chart height of \"%s\": %s", chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getTitle(), height);
  var top = chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getTop();
  Logger.log("Chart top of \"%s\": %s", chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getTitle(), top);
  var left = chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getLeft();
  Logger.log("Chart left of \"%s\": %s", chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].getTitle(), left);

  //remove the linked chart from this sheet before creating a new one
  chartToRemoveLinkedChart.getSheetsCharts()[0].remove();

  presentationStaffChartId = "ga66641c4d9_0_11"; //you need to give your own unique id
  
  var requests = [{
    "createSheetsChart": {
      "objectId": presentationStaffChartId,
      "spreadsheetId": spreadsheetId,
      "chartId": chartId,
      "linkingMode": "NOT_LINKED_IMAGE",
      "elementProperties": {
        "pageObjectId": sheetObjectId,
        "size": {
          "width": {
            "magnitude": width,
            "unit": "PT"
          },
          "height": {
            "magnitude": height,
            "unit": "PT"
          }
        },
        "transform": {
          "scaleX": 1,
          "scaleY": 1,
          "translateX": left,
          "translateY": top,
          "unit": "PT"
        }
      }
    }
  }];
  
  // Execute the request.
  var batchUpdateResponse = Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({
    requests: requests
  }, presentationId);
  
}
```